# EF Core 7 ExecuteUpdateAsync executing before transaction CommitAsync

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have the following code and the issue is that the `ExecuteUpdateAsync` gets executed in the database as soon as it is called. I added a breakpoint in `await dbContext.EventValues.AddRangeAsync(eventValues);` and I can see that values are updated in database. Does `ExecuteUpdateAsync` work with transactions?

```
var dbContext = dbContextPool.CreateDbContext();
var executionStrategy = dbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();

await executionStrategy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
{
    await using (var transaction = await dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
    {
        DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
        
        await dbContext.Events.IgnoreQueryFilters()
            .Where(x => events.Select(y => y.Id).Contains(x.Id))
            .ExecuteUpdateAsync(p => p
                .SetProperty(s => s.IsResolved, true)
                .SetProperty(x => x.ResolvedOn, timestamp));                

        await dbContext.EventValues.AddRangeAsync(eventValues);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        

        await transaction.CommitAsync();
    }
});
```

Comment: Just remove `transaction.CommitAsync();` and you'll see noting will change in the end.