# Several ExecuteUpdate-s in transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Is it possible to run several `ExecuteUpdateAsync` methods in 1 transaction?

For example, I have to bulk update several sets of data, but if later updates fail, want to rollback earlier updates

```
await _context.Groups
              .Where(a => request.Groups.Contains(a.Guid))
              .ExecuteUpdateAsync(s => s.SetProperty(u => u.ServiceId, u => request.ServiceId), cancellationToken);
await _context.Services
              .Where(a => ...)
              .ExecuteUpdateAsync(s => s.SetProperty(...), cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75724203/ef-core-7-executeupdateasync-executing-before-transaction-commitasync

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just open a transaction directly on the `Database` object

```cs
await using (var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(cancellationToken))
{
    await _context
              .Groups
              .Where(a => request.Groups.Contains(a.Guid))
              .ExecuteUpdateAsync(s => s.SetProperty(u => u.ServiceId, u => request.ServiceId),
                   cancellationToken);

    await _context
              .Services
              .Where(a => ...)
              .ExecuteUpdateAsync(s => s.SetProperty(...),
                   cancellationToken);

    await transaction.CommitAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```